# Не работает checkbox и reset в форме

Tags: html5

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=width-device" initial-scale="1.0">
    <title>Мой первый урок web разработки</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 style="color:red"> Мой первый урок Web разработки </h1>
    <from action="/" methot=""> 
<input type="text" name="namePerson" maxlength="13" placeholder="Иван"><br>
<input type="text" name="firsname" maxlength="16" placeholder="Васельков"><br>
<input type="password" name="pass" maxlength="32"><br>
<input type="checkbox" name=""><br>
<input type="reset" name="">
<input type="submit" name="">

    </from>
</html>
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: у вас неправильно написан тег form и атрибут method

Answer (score 3):

Не from, а form. И в заголовке не надо здороваться и излагать полностью проблему.

```
<form action="/" method="">
  <input type="text" name="namePerson" maxlength="13" placeholder="Иван"><br>
  <input type="text" name="firsname" maxlength="16" placeholder="Васельков"><br>
  <input type="password" name="pass" maxlength="32"><br>
  <input type="checkbox" name=""><br>
  <input type="reset" name="">
  <input type="submit" name="">
</form>
```